# Can't connect to IndexedDB in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, indexeddb

My code:

```
var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB;
if(indexedDB) {
  const request = window.indexedDB.open("library", 1);
  let db;

  request.onupgradeneeded = function() {
    console.log("Upgrade")
  };

  request.onsuccess = function() {
    db = request.result;
    console.log(db)
  };
  request.onerror = (event) => {
    console.log('error: ',event)
  }
}
```

I got error in console:

[image: console error]

How can I connet to IndexedDB in IE11 ?

Comment: Do you ***really*** need IE11 support? It's support for indexedDB is patchy at best: https://caniuse.com/?search=indexeddb

Comment: Unfortunately we should support our app on IE11 too

Comment: IE11 has fallen to around 0.5% usage worldwide, it is no longer supported and Microsoft is actively removing it. By June this year it will be gone everywhere but a few isolated places on the Internet. Whatever effort you put into this now will be wasted.

Comment: Are you referring to Internet Explorer 11, the browser the Microsoft officially killed of a few weeks ago and is actively uninstalling them from existing Windows installations?

Comment: _"Unfortunately we should support our app on IE11 too"_ I would actively push back on this to those who are insisting on this. What versions of Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera, etc. are you also supporting. I'd bet they are nowhere near as old as IE 11!